# How do I reference an OSM object?

Tags: openstreetmap

I need to keep a record of the OpenStreetMap objects that I have edited. But I can't see any IDs attached to road segments & the URL doesn't change when I select them.

How can I uniquely identify road segments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track all your edits using this url: http://www.openstreetmap.org/user/YourOSMUserNameGoesHere/history 
To uniquely identify your osm objects simply select one of the change-sets listed and you'll be provided with a link to every single osm feature.

Answer (score 4):

If you enable the data layer on high zoom, you can click at the OSM elements and see their internal ID https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements#Common_attributes
Keep in mind that these IDs aren't absolut stable (splitting ways, ...) and can be altered by users (remove and reupload the data). So you might consider other ways to refer OSM objects as address, streetname, ...